# SharePoint Search returning too many results

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, search-results, 2016

I am using SharePoint Search on a Custom List (SharePoint 2016) and it is returning too many results which do not seem to match with the original Search.

What is the procedure to enforce SharePoint to carry out an exact match on Search?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend setting up a search schema in order to carry out more precise searches. By default search schema only crawl text fields. For instance Title:Doc1 as mentioned in the previous answers. However, it is possible to accommodate for other data types by modifying existing schema groups.

Microsoft already has some decent documentation on managing search schema. Please refer to:

**Text & Yes No fields:**
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-search-schema#create-a-new-managed-property

**Ohter data types (e.g date)**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-search-schema#create-a-managed-property-by-renaming-an-existing-one

I hope you find the above resources helpful!

Comment: Once you have set up your schema do not forget to re crawl your library.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for specific property it like this:

```
Title:Doc1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [KQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to manage your keyword for a better search result. Both Title:Doc1 or Title=Doc1 
[image]